# Select ordered sublists of Permutations[{p1, p2, p3, p4}, {2}]

Tags: sorting, permutation, filtering

Given:

```
Permutations[{p2,p3,p5,p7}, {2}]

(*
{{p2, p3}, {p2, p5}, {p2, p7}, {p3, p2}, {p3, p5}, {p3, p7}, {p5, 
  p2}, {p5, p3}, {p5, p7}, {p7, p2}, {p7, p3}, {p7, p5}}
*)
```

I want the ordered items selected:

```
{{p2, p3}, {p2, p5}, {p2, p7}, {p3, p5}, {p3, p7}, {p5, p7}}
```

In general this list `{p1,p2,...,pm}` will vary and the number of tuples will vary from 1 to m.

Important-this needs to work for symbolic values, p1, p2, ..., pm, and numerical values.  Thus the function

```
Elist[p_List, m_] := 
  Map[Variables, Union[Map[Total, Permutations[p, {m}]]]];
```

will work for symbols but not numerical values due to the Variables function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`OrderedQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OrderedQ.html)

```
Select[Permutations[{p1, p2, p3, p4}, {2}], OrderedQ]

(* {{p1, p2}, {p1, p3}, {p1, p4}, {p2, p3}, {p2, p4}, {p3, p4}} *)

Select[Permutations[{p1, p2, 1, 4}, {2}], OrderedQ]

(* {{p1, p2}, {1, p1}, {1, p2}, {1, 4}, {4, p1}, {4, p2}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use [`Subsets`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subsets)?

```
Subsets[Sort @ {p1, p2, p3, p4}, {2}]

Subsets[Sort @ {p1, p2, 1, 4}, {2}]
```

> {{p1, p2}, {p1, p3}, {p1, p4}, {p2, p3}, {p2, p4}, {p3, p4}}
>
> {{1, 4}, {1, p1}, {1, p2}, {4, p1}, {4, p2}, {p1, p2}}

*(the first [`Sort`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sort) is not necessary since the variables are already sorted, but I included it for clarity)*